# How can I write to an output file?

Tags: java

How can I write the bottom section to an output file? It compiles and runs, but shuts down instead of writing it to the file.

I import everything correctly.  But my outfile will not print to TEACHERNAME.out?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Date;
public class Corpus03
{
  public static void main(String arg[])
   throws FileNotFoundException
   {

   Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));
   PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("TEACHERNAME.out"); 

       //INPUT
   name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name: ");
   ID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your ID: ");
   str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Annual Salary");
   annualSalary = Double.parseDouble(str);
   //CALCULATIONS
   grossPayPerCheck = annualSalary / 24;
   actualDayWorked = annualSalary / 174;
   perWeek = (annualSalary / 50);
   perHour = perWeek / 40; 
   ssTax = grossPayPerCheck * SS_TAX;
   medTax = grossPayPerCheck * MED_TAX;
   fedTax = grossPayPerCheck * FED_TAX;
   stateTax = grossPayPerCheck * STATE_TAX;
   unitedWay = 20;
   healthIns = 125;
   totalDeductions = ssTax + medTax + fedTax + stateTax + healthIns +    unitedWay;
   netPay = (grossPayPerCheck - totalDeductions);
   Date now = new Date();
   //OUTPUT
   outputStr = "Name: " + name
      + "\r\n" + "Employee ID: " + ID
      + "\r\n" + "Annual Salary: " + String.format("%.2f", annualSalary)
      + "\r\n" + "Gross Pay per Check: $"
      + String.format("%.2f", grossPayPerCheck)
      + "\r\n" + "$" + String.format("%.2f", actualDayWorked) + " per actual day worked"
      + "\r\n" + "$" + String.format("%.2f", perHour) + " per hour"
      + "\r\n\r\n" + "===================="
      + "\r\n" + "DEDUCTIONS PER CHECK"
      + "\r\n" + "===================="
      + "\r\n" + "Social Security Tax: $" 
      + String.format("%.2f", ssTax)
      + "\r\n" + "Medicare Tax: $"
      + String.format("%.2f", medTax)
      + "\r\n" + "Federal Income: $"
      + String.format("%.2f", fedTax)
      + "\r\n" + "State Income Tax: $"
      + String.format("%.2f", stateTax)
      + "\r\n" + "Health Insurance: $125.00"
      + "\r\n" + "United Way Contribution: $20.00"
      + "\r\n\r\n" + "Total Deductions: $" 
      + String.format("%.2f", totalDeductions)
      + "\r\n\r\n" + "Net Pay per check: $" 
      + String.format("%.2f", netPay);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputStr, 
                     "Teacher Pay Information", 
                   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   outFile.printf("City School Dstric, 111 First Stree, Anytown, OK 12345");
   outFile.println();
   outFile.println();
   outFile.printf("%-40s%-10s\r\n\n", name, ID);
   outFile.close();  
   inputFile.close();
   System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

The only thing my code doesn't do is write to a separate text file. (Yes, I have more that I need to write to the text file I was just giving an example of some of the things I needed.)

Comment: where is your `name` and `ID` params ?

Comment: I have those, I just shortened my code to the questions I have. I couldn't format the whole code to four spaces
   name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name: ");
   ID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your ID: ");

Comment: I run your code and, i can create TEACHERNAME.out object. Where is your workspace ?

Comment: Don't have the main method throw an exception. Instead try/catch any exceptions within main, and print the stacktrace. Also put in some debugging code, code that proves that you're actually reading from the input file.

Comment: There's a whole bunch more to this code. I just didn't understand why it wasn't writing to the file? My code runs and compiles correctly just doesn't write ANYTHING to the file.

Comment: Can you write your workspace path?

Comment: I think your problem with permisson. Change your workspace , you dont have permission to write file to some classes.

Comment: my workspace? What is that

Comment: where is your codes in system ? click any .class file and right click --> copy path and paste here

Comment: OHHHH . shit thank you so much drowny!! I remember the book saying you need to make the .txt file where the main class is.. so  id put C:\\blah\blah\TEACHERNAME.txt)); ?

Comment: Write file to anywhere which you have a permisson. glad to help you :) good lucks

Comment: just a hint: `PrintWriter` methods do not throw IOException, you should use `checkError()`.(I prefer working with other `Writer` and get an Exception...)

Comment: Well I tried that but now it's saying my \ are illegal characters.  I have 
 PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("C:\Users\myname\Documents\TEACHERNAME.out");

Comment: hmm.. thank you Carlos. I am not sure I've learned checkError() yet but I will look into it!! I appreciate it.

Comment: backslash is an escape character, you need two of them to represent one (get compiled into one)

Comment: Write \\ for each \ in `new PrintWriter("C:\Users\myname\Documents\TEACHERNAME.out")`.

Comment: IT works!!! thank you to everyone who helped!! I feel like a fool missing this easy '\\' . I appreciate all of you helped

Answer (score 0):

You can give relative path to `PrintWriter` as

```
PrintWriter outFile = 
            new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\example\\IdeaProjects\\untitled\\news\\TEACHERNAME.out");
```

**Dont forget** to escape `\` as `\\`. Now you can see the `TEACHERNAME.out` in absolute path.